# How to access the Magento API from native client with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oauth, api

I need to access the Magento API from a local JavaScript based application (Titanium Desktop) and wondering what's the best way to do so.

**What I found out so far:**

- The only authentication mechanism is OAuth, so the user has to enter their credentials on site
- There is a JavaScript client library: https://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/#svn%2Fcode%2Fjavascript
- For native apps as OAuth clients, the [OAuth 2 User Agent Flow](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/27249271/OAuth%202%20for%20Native%20Apps) is recommended.
- The redirect URL has to point to a local page from where the token has to be extracted or copy&pasted

**Questions:**

- Is it feasible to exchange the authentication mechanism to something like HMAC based authentication with application key and secret? Are there even proven solutions?
- If not, is the OAuth User Agent Flow possible with Magento? The documentation does not mention it.
- Is it possible to submit the user credentials with AJAX (Cross-Origin-Policy is not an issue here) to hide most of the authorization process from the user? The access token could then possibly be extracted directly from the response.

Comment: OK, I found out that I was too focused on REST, the SOAP API should solve my problem, though SOAP with JavaScript is kind of cumbersome. There is a library for Titanium (https://github.com/kwhinnery/Suds), I will try it out and post the results here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Edit: Found a better way, see Solution 2 below**

As mentioned in the comment, the SOAP API is the way to go.

### Solution 1:

[Suds](https://github.com/kwhinnery/Suds) worked for me with slight modification (Usage of `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`), but it does not much more than creating a SOAP envelope for the call and returning the whole XML response.

Proof-of-Concept implementation, using jQuery [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) for request chaining:

```
Service.MagentoClient = function()
{
    var self = this;
    var suds = new SudsClient({
        endpoint : "http://the-magento-host/api/v2_soap/",
        targetNamespace : "urn:Magento",
    });

    self.login = function() {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        var args = {
            username : 'the-username',
            apiKey: 'the-api-key'
        };
        suds.invoke("login", args, function(xmlDoc) {
            self.sessionId = $(xmlDoc).find("loginReturn").text();
            deferred.resolve({});
            //TODO reject if no sessionid returned
        });
        return deferred;
    };

    self.setStatus = function(orderId, status, comment, notify) {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        if (!self.sessionId) {
            deferred.reject({ error: 'Login not successful.' });
            return;
        }
        var args = {
            sessionId        : self.sessionId,
            orderIncrementId : orderId,
            status           : status,
            comment          : comment,
            notify           : notify
        }
        suds.invoke("salesOrderAddComment", args, function(xmlDoc) {
            var success = $(xmlDoc).find("salesOrderAddCommentResponse").text();
            if (success) {
                deferred.resolve({});
            } else {
                deferred.reject({ error: 'Update not successful.' });
            }

        });
        return deferred;
    };
};
```

**Usage example:**

```
        var magento = new Service.MagentoClient();
        magento.login().then(function() {
            magento.setStatus('100000029', 'complete', 'soap test');
        }).then(function() {
            alert('Update successful');
        }, function(reject) {
            alert('Update failed: ' + reject.error);
        });
```

### Solution 2:

Turned out that writing an own API adapter can be really easy. With the example of <del>[this core-hack](https://github.com/ratazzi/magento-jsonrpc-adapter/blob/master/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Jsonrpc.php)</del> (dead link) I was able to write a clean module for a JSON-RPC adapter based on `Zend_Json_Server`. It uses the same Authentication and ACL as the SOAP and XML-RPC APIs.

To use the entry point `/api/jsonrpc`, the new controller has to be added to the `api` route:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <api>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <my_jsonrpc before="Mage_Api">My_JsonRpc_Api</my_jsonrpc>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </api>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> **Update 02/2015:** The above link is dead now, so I open sourced my JSON-RPC adapter as a complete extension: https://github.com/sgh-it/jsonrpc

My JS client now looks like this (again with JQuery.Deferred, but no additional 3rd party libraries for the API):

```
/**
 * Client for the Magento API
 */
Service.MagentoClient = function()
{
    var self = this;

    /**
     * @param string   method    the remote procedure to call
     * @param object   params    parameters for the RPC
     * @param callback onSuccess callback for successful request. Expects one parameter (decoded response object)
     * @param callback onError   callback for failed request. Expects one parameter (error message)
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    self.jsonRpc = function(method, params, onSuccess, onError) {
        var request = {
            method : method,
            params : params,
            jsonrpc : "2.0",
            id : 1
        };

        var options = {
            entryPoint : config.magentoClient.entryPoint,
            method: 'post',
            timeout: config.magentoClient.timeout
        };

        var httpClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        httpClient.onload = function(e) {
            try {
                var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            } catch (jsonError) {
                return onError(jsonError);
            }
            if (response.error) {
                if (response.error.code == 5) { // session expired
                    self.sessionId = null;
                }
                return onError(response.error.message);
            }
            onSuccess(response);
        };
        httpClient.onerror = function(e) {
            onError(e.error + '; Response:' + this.responseText);
        };
        httpClient.setTimeout(options.timeout);

        if (httpClient.open(options.method, options.entryPoint)) {
            httpClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpClient.send(JSON.stringify(request));
        } else {
            onError('cannot open connection');
        }

    }
    /**
     * Retrieve session id for API
     * 
     * @return JQuery.Deferred deferred object for asynchronous chaining
     */
    self.login = function() {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        if (self.sessionId) {
            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred;
        }
        var loginParams = config.magentoClient.login;
        try {
            self.jsonRpc('login', loginParams, function(response) {
                if (response && response.result) {
                    self.sessionId = response.result;
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject('Login failed.');
                }
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        } catch (rpcError) {
            deferred.reject(rpcError);
        }
        return deferred;
    };
    /**
     * Updates order states in Magento
     *
     * @param string method   name of the remote method
     * @param object args     arguments for the remote method
     * 
     * @return JQuery.Deferred deferred object for asynchronous chaining
     */
    self.call = function(method, args) {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        if (!self.sessionId) {
            deferred.reject('No session.');
            return;
        }
        var callParams = {
            sessionId : self.sessionId,
            apiPath   : method,
            args      : args
        };
        try {
            self.jsonRpc('call', callParams, function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.result);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        } catch (rpcError) {
            deferred.reject(rpcError);
        }

        return deferred;
    };
};
```

Note that all methods after login are routed through `call`. The `method` parameter is something like `sales_order.list`, the `args` parameter an array or object with the method arguments.

**Usage example:**

```
        var filters = [];
        var magento = new Service.MagentoClient();
        magento.login().then(function() {
            magento.call('sales_order.list', [filters]).then(
                function(orders) {
                    // do something with the response
                }, function(error) {
                    alert('Magento API error: ' + error);
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: How to configure endpoint in your script?

Comment: You have to change the frontend router definition in `config.xml` (if you don't want to use the `api` route, you can also use a custom route instead, define it as you would in any other Magento module

Comment: Where I can put this code in magento

Comment: Installation instructions are there: https://github.com/sgh-it/jsonrpc

Comment: And the JavaScript code obviously does not belong in Magento but in the external client