# Magento : How to show data of external api using custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, api, rest-api

I want to create a `custom module` in which, I want to fetch some `external data using API` and show them at home page or any location.

I have API's ready , now i want to fetch data in my custom module and show them in my website.

I have never worked with API in magento. Can any one suggest any link or method so that I can start.

Comment: Check link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13343

Comment: i want to show data from another source