# How to call Magento SOAP API using Jquery?

Tags: soap, jquery

I would like to call magento SOAP using Javascript or Jquery to list the products.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think doing SOAP with JS is hell. And I don't know why you would like to do this with SOAP?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcq9vOgS-Ao

Comment: http://de.slideshare.net/meetmagentoes/one-page-shops-with-magento-angular-js-vinai

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the Magento API from native client with JavaScript](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-to-access-the-magento-api-from-native-client-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to NOT use SOAP. I think SOAP with JS is horrible, because you can not easily create all stubs and stuff, which you canc reate in every other language - if you can, do it!

Instead I recommend to use the REST API:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Products

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we have created an angular js app, and I need to get product list, add to cart then order ... I think that magento REST API doesn't allow to create an order.
It Only allow to list data

Comment: But it is kinda easy to enhance the REST API to fullfill your requirements. For some cases there are already writing operations but order management is a bit of a problem with REST.

Answer (score 1):

I recomment using a JSON adapter for the API instead, which works much nicer with JavaScript than SOAP. You can use the same API as XML-RPC (i.e. SOAP v1)

I created a very simple adapter here: https://github.com/sgh-it/jsonrpc

More details in this similar question: [How to access the Magento API from native client with JavaScript](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-to-access-the-magento-api-from-native-client-with-javascript/514)

Comment: I have already checked out your adapter, but I didn't understand how to use it, I have imported the file into magento. Can you provide me with an example on how to list all products for example if my link is "http://192.168.59.132/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" ?