# Magento 1.9.x Rest API

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

Can someone explain to me why I need Oauth to query a list of products for a guest?

I don't understand, I just want a JSON of the product properties for my JavaScript, why do I need this Oauth procedure when dealing with the Rest API?

Or should I just echo out the models contents in `json_encode()` and do it that way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 1, the REST API is only made for OAuth clients, and as you noticed this does not make sense for your use case. A useful general REST API was introduced in Magento 2.

Instead, there is XML-RPC and SOAP and you can implement JSON-RPC on your own with very little effort (see: [How to access the Magento API from native client with JavaScript](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-to-access-the-magento-api-from-native-client-with-javascript))

> Or should I just echo out the models contents in `json_encode()` and do it that way?

If that's a possible alternative for you, you don't need the API and I would recommend to do it like that.